# Help showing equality involving $\tan$ function

Tags: trigonometry

$$\Large\frac{\left(\frac{\tan \frac \pi 4+\tan x}{1-\tan\frac \pi 4\tan x}\right)}{\left(\frac{\tan \frac \pi 4-\tan x}{1+\tan\frac \pi 4\tan x}\right)}=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}\right)}$$

I am having a little trouble figuring out how we got from the first step to the other one. It would be really appreciated if someone could help me out. Note that this is not an assignment question, these are all solved examples, only for my practice.

Comment: whats the value of $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})$ ?

Comment: $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=?$ Draw the circle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\tan\frac\pi4=1\hspace{5mm} ;-){}{}{}{}$$

Comment: I feel soooooo stupid when doing trigonometry! :D Thanks. :)

Comment: Feeling stupid is actually what makes us to move forward and remember things and importantly be better at things! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for that. :) My exam is in one month and my math is a bit weak, so I'm kindda worried...

Comment: Practice a lot, with time you will be way better and you'll pass your exam ;) Just keep practicing a lot

Comment: @AkshatTripathi. Good luck for your exam !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks and I think that after a year of Stackoverflow, this is going to be my new best friend for this month! ;) :D

Comment: @AkshatTripathi. This is a very, very, very good site ! I learn every single day and I bet I am older than your grand parents ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Wow! After so many years, still passionate about mathematics, I salute you, sir! :)

Comment: @AkshatTripathi. Thank you ! I have a lot of fun with mathematics and I was very bad when young ! Work, work and discover the pure beauty !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That was really motivating, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1$$